# How do I create a new text file after every loop in a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, createfile

I have a piece of text which I want to write in different text files, so I'm using a while loop to create a new txt file after every loop. However I don't know how to create a new text file AFTER every loop has been completed. For the text, I have a variable outside the loop, so the text is not an issue. I just don't know how to create new multiple files, without rewriting the existing txt file. Can someone please help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just generate a different filename every time you open the file for writing that would do.
Or best would be not to create multiple files. Just write into one file and create (no_of_copies-1) symlinks with  different names. This would be efficient.

Comment: i was thinking of doing that, however if i want to create for example 100 txt files, doing the above method would be time consuming and ineffecient, but thank you!